# How to select class dependent features?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, feature-selection

Suppose, I have a data set which contains **two classes** and more than **50,000 features**. Most of the works I have found try to select features which distinguishes two classes. We called those selected features most important features. But which features are most relevant to which class can't be defined by those approaches that I want to know. For example,

```
              f1    f2    f3 ....... f50000      class
sample 1:     .5    .4     23......... .45         1
sample 2:     .2    .56     .5......... .45        2
sample 3:     .4    56     .23......... .45        2
sample 4:     .3    .45     76......... .45        1
```

Here, f1= feature 1, f2=feature2 etc.

Suppose, Somehow I know, `f1, f2, f3, f45, f344` is related with `class 1`, and `f4, f5, f6, f90, f99` are related with `class 2`. Other features are not related with those classes. So the output be,

```
class1: f1, f2,f3,f45,f344
class2: f4,f5,f6,f90,f99
```

What will be the algorithms ?
It will be very helpful for me if anyone gives me any papers(deep learning or others) or references. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to detect the significance of the features. A simple approach would be truncating features with low variance. Have a look at [this scikit article](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) if you'd like to use their implementation.

An other common why is to penalize the amount of features with L1/L2 regularization. This prevents the algorithm from using all weights. An implementation is in the same scikit article. I just found [this github post](https://github.com/pickus91/Logistic-Regression-Classifier-with-L2-Regularization) which explains quite shortly and well the L2 regularization in combination with logistic regression.